# Chunked uploads with react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, dropzone, react-dropzone

I would like to upload chunked files using React-Dropzone. I have the following code:

**OnDrop:**

```
const dropTest = async (file, rejectedFiles) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(appContext.api_url + 'ApiUser/fileUpload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      const result = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}
```

**Render:**

```
<Dropzone onDrop={dropTest} chunking={true}>
  {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => (
      <section>
         <div {...getRootProps()}>
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
          </div>
      </section>
  )}
</Dropzone>
```

Dropzone library has an api, name of {chunking: true}, but It's not working on react-dropzone, how can I archieve this?

If it is not possible with React-Dropzone, I can get suggestions about another chunking upload solutions for react.

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: can recommend https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady - a little because I wrote it, but also because it handles this use-case and much more :)

Comment: Loading the file from the file system and uploading it to a server are two different steps. You could load the full file from the file system (via `react-dropzone`), and still send it in chunks to the server, if that's feasible for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, react-dropzone does not support chunking.
Those features are available in the [fineuploader](https://fineuploader.com/) librairie (it is supported in REACT here is the [link](https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader)).
It gives you the ability to build DropZone, ProgressBar, Chunking, Retry and much more. It is also well documented.

Answer (score 1):

for React + DnD + Chunked Upload, I recommend [react-uploady](https://react-uploady.org) (and not just because I wrote it).

This is how simple it is to get a drop-zone + chunked uploading working:

```js
import ChunkedUploady from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadDropZone  from "@rpldy/upload-drop-zone";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ChunkedUploady
     destination={{ url: "[upload-url]" }}>
        <UploadDropZone>
          Drop File here...
        </UploadDropZone>
      </div>
    </ChunkedUploady>
  );
}
```

And it supports every feature related to uploading from the browser.

Here's a sample sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/chunked-upload-dnd-2k6rqt?file=/src/App.js:40-139